# Do all Mac OS X versions (above 10.4) have python preinstalled?

Tags: python, macos

Do all **Mac OS X** versions (above 10.4) have **python** preinstalled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they do all have python preinstalled.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, but the Python version may be different. OS X 10.5 shipped with Python 2.5, OS X 10.6 with Python 2.6.

Comment: ...and 10.4 (at least 10.4.11) shipped with Python 2.3.5.

Answer (score -1):

Yes they do. Use it from Terminal.

Comment: MacOS X uses the Mach microkernel, whereas both FreeBSD and NetBSD use a monolithic kernel - they are very, very different.  It is a "BSD-like" system evolved from NeXTSTEP, but by no means does it bear anything other than a cosmetic relation to modern FreeBSD.

Comment: What's you problem man. As I know it certain parts from FreeBSD's and NetBSD's implementation of Unix were incorporated in NeXTSTEP, the core of Mac OS X. That's what I wanted to put across. You just had to go into it did you? No need to be so harsh.

Comment: the kernel is not one of the parts that were incorporated into NeXTSTEP; the userland tools were, but Python has nothing to do with BSD.